# Open source Rails projects with great RSpec usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

For learning purposes, I'm looking for open source Rails projects that exemplify idiomatic usage of RSpec for BDD.  I can find projects, but I'm not experienced enough with Rails or RSpec to know whether what I'm looking at represents best practices. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had a look and [Insoshi](http://github.com/insoshi/insoshi/tree/master) seems to have a good comprehensive set of specs. Mephisto has a limited set of clean specs.

Answer (score 2):

There is the [The Rspec Book](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/achbd/the-rspec-book) in beta, it is co-authored by David Chelimsky, the lead developer of Rspec.